# Should VS Code work the same if I update my PC from Windows 10 to Windows 11?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, windows-11

Will VS Code work the same way if I update my laptop to Windows 11 from Windows 10? Or do I have to re-install VS Code again after updating with Windows 11?

I'm about to update my PC with 11. Needed to know before I update as to the required update in VS code.
If anyone can tell if I should go ahead.

Comment: I assume it will work just fine but you can always [sync your VSCode config](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) to create a backup

Answer (score 1):

Updating your PC from windows 10 to windows 11 will not change anything in VS Code, everything will remain the same, even your settings, themes, extensions, etc